# How to make a single rotation edit in a global axis but across the entire animation?

Tags: animation, transforms, graph-editor, motion-capture

I have a mocap animation which is wrongly placed and rotated; the root bone is located at X= -184 and so on, and is at about 30 degrees in the global Z axis in the starting frame, which is frame #2.

I've fixed the position through the graph editor, so the location is not an issue, but I don't know how to fix the rotation so that it is aligned with the Y axis for the love of my life.

The solution would be to simply **rotate** the root bone in pose mode by -30 degrees **in global Z**; the problem is, **how do you do that across all frames?**

You can manipulate the local rotation values in graph editor, but not the global ones.
Also, is bad starting rotation and location a common motion capture problem? If so, what's the term for that?
Here's the blend file if you want to take a look: https://pasteall.org/blend/452db145f94a41c9a650c3438ecde929

[image: Showcase of the problem:]

Comment: I think you can just take all those keyframes related to Z axis in your graph view and pull them by 30 down or up(not sure which way is +/-) can you try?

Comment: No, because those are rotation values in relation to the local axes. It would probably work if there was a way to see global rotation values in the graph editor, but I'm not aware of any such option. Here's what happens if I try to pull it as you say - it changes the local Z rotation value, which is completely wrong:
https://prnt.sc/1nd9f8v

Comment: You can add Child Of constraint with a rotated target, then bake the animation with "Clear Constraints".